# django select_for_update(nowait=False) in transaction.atomic() does not work as expected

Tags: django

I have a django app that needs to get a unique ID. Many threads run at the same time that need one. I would like the IDs to be sequential. When I need a unique ID I do this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    max_batch_id = JobStatus.objects.select_for_update(nowait=False).aggregate(Max('batch_id'))
    json_dict['batch_id'] = max_batch_id['batch_id__max'] + 1
    status_row = JobStatus(**json_dict)
    status_row.save()
```

But multiple jobs are getting the same ID. Why does the code not work as I expect? What is a better way to accomplish what I need? I cannot use the row id as there are many rows that have the same batch_id.

Answer (score 0):

As Django docs says in [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields), you can use `F()` for avoiding race condition:

> The process can be made robust, avoiding a race condition, as well as slightly faster by expressing the update relative to the original field value, rather than as an explicit assignment of a new value. Django provides F expressions for performing this kind of relative update.

So you probably want sth like this:

```py
...
max_batch_id = JobStatus.objects.select_for_update(nowait=False).aggregate(Max(F('batch_id')))
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not fix the problem. Looking at the docs it seems I need to use the F() when I am adding 1, not when selecting it. Also all the examples are updating a row - I need to add a new row.

Comment: Going to try this: `max_batch_id = JobStatus.objects.select_for_update(nowait=False).aggregate(Max(F('batch_id')))['batch_id__max']+1` but not sure if it will work when I assign max_batch_id to a new instance of JobStatus.

Comment: That did not work. Still getting duplicate batch ids.

Comment: I ended up using another table to get the batch_ids from. It works, but I still wonder how to make it work without a second table.